# Are there sufficient conditions for a curve in Rn to be "strictly convex"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I do not know if this is a question for this page or for mathoverflow.

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and let $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^\infty$-curve which is $2\pi$-periodic and has no self-intersections, i.e. we have
$(\forall s,t\in\mathbb R)\ \gamma(s)=\gamma(t) \iff s-t\in 2\pi\mathbb Z$.

It is clear to me that the image $C:=\gamma(\mathbb R)\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is compact.
This implies (since everything is finite dimensional) that the convex hull $\mathrm{co}C\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is compact as well.
Now, consider $E:= \mathrm{extreme}(\mathrm{co}C)\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ the set of extreme points of this convex set.

By Milman's (partial) converse to the Krein–Milman theorem (as found on wikipedia) we have the following set inclusion:
$E \subseteq C$.

It is easy to see that in general $E\neq C$.

Let us for the moment call $\gamma$ *strictly convex* if equality $E=C$ holds.

I am now looking for sufficient criteria for $\gamma$ to be strictly convex in this setting.

It looks plausible that in dimension $n=2$ a curve with the above properties (smooth, periodic, no self-intersections) is strictly convex if $\gamma'(t)$ and $\gamma''(t)$ are linearly independent at each point. Intuitively, this means that the curve always lurns left or always turns right.

**Question 1**: Is this true? If so, can you give me a proof or a reference? If not, obviously, something similar has to be true, what are the correct hypotheses?

**Question 2**: It is clear that for $n>2$ linear independence of the first and second derivative is no longer sufficient but is there maybe something similar? Maybe that all linear projections onto 2-dimensional spaces are strictly convex or something like that?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve#Strict_convexity) is the notion of strict convexity you are interested in. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Thanks for the link. In 2dimensions, the notion in the linked article is most likely equivalent to "my" definition, the problem is: I do not directly see why. And the connected to the linear independence of the derivatives is also not clear to me...

Comment: Doesn't it seem reasonable to suggest that $E=C$ if and only if $C$ is contained in a two-dimensional affine subspace?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I don't think so. If I plot the curve (cos(t),sin(t),cos(2t)), it looks as if E=C, but of course just staring at a plot is not a good proof